# What is wrong with the left join?

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I am using postgres and I am trying to join two tables using left join. I want all the columns from the left and all of the columns from the right to be included.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b on
a.id = b.id;
```

When I run this there are no new columns, and only the columns from table1 are in the table. I cannot figure out what is wrong. I tried to do an outer join as well but still there were no new columns in table1.

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
tabel1:
+------------+---------------+--------------+
| id         | COMPANY_NAME  | COMPANY_CITY |
+------------+---------------+--------------+
| 18         | Order All     | Boston       |
| 15         | Jack Hill Ltd | London       |
| 16         | Akas Foods    | Delhi        |
| 17         | Foodies.      | London       |
| 19         | sip-n-Bite.   | New York     |
+------------+---------------+--------------+


table2:
+--------------+-----------+
| ITEM_NAME    | id        |
+--------------+-----------+
| Chex Mix     |  16       |
| Cheez-It     |  15       |
| BN Biscuit   |  15       | 
| Mighty Munch |  17       | 
| Pot Rice     |  15       | 
| Jaffa Cakes  |  18       |
| Salt n Shake |           |
+--------------+-----------+
```

I would like the final results to look like:

```
id         COMPANY_NAME              COMPANY_CITY              ITEM_NAME
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ---------- 
16         Akas Foods                Delhi                     Chex Mix
15         Jack Hill Ltd             London                    Cheez-It
15         Jack Hill Ltd             London                    BN Biscuit
17         Foodies.                  London                    Mighty Munch
15         Jack Hill Ltd             London                    Pot Rice
18         Order All                 Boston                    Jaffa Cakes
19         sip-n-Bite.               New York
```

I also check to make sure that there were matches between the two ids in the different tables and there is.

I ran the query using psql and the output just says:

```
SELECT 2000
```

And then to look to see what columns I had I ran

```
\d table1
```

Here is a link to the sql fiddle that I am trying to accomplish: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/96afa/2

Comment: Please post some representative data.

Comment: It would be helpful to share your data as well. Right now, we have no idea what you are trying to join.

Comment: What tool are you using to run this query?

Comment: @MikeOrganek I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Yes, but what query tool are you using?  pgadmin?  psql?  something else?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly `SELECT *, ITEM_NAME`?

Comment: @MikeOrganek I am using psql

Comment: Can you copy/paste the query and its result from psql? There must be a misunderstanding ...

Comment: Per the comment from @ErwinBrandstetter , please copy/paste from your psql session.  We need to see the issued `select` from your question in addition to the results returned.

Comment: You seem to expect a `SELECT` query to *change*  `table1`. That is not so. `ALTER TABLE` does that ... Or `CREATE TABLE AS` to create a new table ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I added a link to SQL fiddle. It seems to update the table. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Your sample data does not match your fiddle, and the fiddle contains columns NOT question and not in sample data. Please revise the question and/or fiddle so they have same content. Then describe how the fiddle differs from the desired result.

Comment: @izz: `SELECT` does not update anything. It only returns data. I added a line to your fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/96afa/4

Answer (score 1):

> I want all the columns from the left and all of the columns from the right to be included.

Strictly speaking, you don't. Your desired result shows only one `id` column.
You can achieve that with the `USING` clause in the join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 a
LEFT   JOIN table2 b USING (id);
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> A clause of the form `USING ( a, b, ... )` is shorthand for `ON left_table.a = right_table.a AND left_table.b = right_table.b ....`
> Also, `USING` implies that only one of each pair of equivalent columns
> will be included in the join output, not both.

---

This is strictly impossible:

> When I run this there are no new columns, and only the columns from table1 are in the table

Must be a problem with the display in your client. Or some other misunderstanding. Some clients do have problems with duplicate column names - which is eliminated with my query.

This would **[create a new table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html)** from a query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT *
FROM   table1 a
LEFT   JOIN table2 b USING (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify each table's columns explicitly. Using an aterix, it looks like so:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM table1 a
 LEFT JOIN table2 b 
  on a.id = b.id;
```

Tested with the following data in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/90da5/3):

```
create table table1 (id integer, something_else varchar);

insert into table1 values(1, 'abc');
insert into table1 values(2, 'efg');


create table table2 (id integer, different varchar);


insert into table2 values(1, 'hij');
insert into table2 values(99, 'klm');
```

Comment: I tried that as well and had the same problem.

Comment: I see. We're going to need some representative data in order to help you.